# MongoDB-CR Authentication failed

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am getting following error while authenticating user : purchase_user@purchase failed. MongoDB-CR Authentication failed. Missing credentials in user document when I access webservice through browser.

But I am able to authenticate purchase_user from mongo it returns 1 .

Answer (score 84, accepted):

go to mongoDB console and delete your current user & set authSchema version to 3 instead of 5 , follow these commands in mongo console -

```
mongo
use admin
db.system.users.remove({})    <== removing all users
db.system.version.remove({}) <== removing current version 
db.system.version.insert({ "_id" : "authSchema", "currentVersion" : 3 })
```

Now restart the mongod and create new user then it should work fine.

Note: use remove commands in test db only, if in production use update.

#### Authentication information for Kubernetes Helm Chart

If you delete the all users and authentication is enabled in the configuration (or `--auth` param which is set per default on the Kubernetes helm chart), it's not possible to access MongoDB any more. Its required to disable authentication, create a new user and then re-enable it.

On Kubernetes you need to edit the parameters and add `--noauth` as argument, since it's not the default there as on a classic installed MongoDB. Please see [the CLI documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod-noauth) for more information about `--noauth` and the corresponding `--auth`.

Comment: This could not cause any inconsistency or security problem? For the record, your solution solved my problem.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. Just for learning, why this issue raises?

Comment: Just have in mind that, BEFORE DOWNGRADING THE SCHEMA, you should DISABLE authentication, otherwise your user will be invalidated as soon as you remove the users from db.system.users.  Take care

Comment: removing FeatureCompatibilityVersion document is not allowed

Comment: there is a problem when removing current version it says "FeatureCompatibilityVersion document is not allowed "

Answer (score 20):

Had the same issue. What was happening to me was that when I use MongoDB 3 to create my user, it was using SCRAM-SHA-1 as it's authentication mechanism instead of MongoDB-CR. What I had to do was:

1. List item
2. Delete the created user.
3. Modify the collection admin.system.version such that the authSchema's currentVersion is 3 instead of 5 (3 is using MongoDB-CR).
4. Recreate your user.

Should work without problems now.

Comment: This one should be marked as an correct answer, for sure.

Comment: how do you modify admin.system.version ?

Answer (score 19):

The step number 2. above is not detailed explicitly, I found this solution and worked for me.

```
var schema = db.system.version.findOne({"_id" : "authSchema"})
schema.currentVersion = 3
db.system.version.save(schema)
```

Comment: where do I do this? And what user privileges does it require? I get "not authorized for query on admin.system.version" when I try.

Comment: Hey @MarcMaxson see my response below. You need to delete your initial admin and recreate one after running the commands acabra provided. Any admin you created prior to making the schema change won't work. This drove me crazy as well.

Comment: @acabra85 thank for you step. This step mix with top answer help me fix that problems.

Answer (score 13):

I think this is the answer you need:

1) Start 3.0 without auth enabled. (Auth needs to be disabled otherwise you'll get the not authorized error).

2) Run (after selecting "admin"use  db):

> var schema = db.system.version.findOne({"_id" : "authSchema"})
>
> schema.currentVersion = 3
>
> db.system.version.save(schema)

3) restart mongodb with auth enabled.

4) Create a new admin user (the old one, the one you created before this workaround won't work).

Things should work now. This issue was driving me crazy as well.

Answer came from here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17459

Answer (score 9):

Adding to above solution by Vivek & explanation taken [from here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17459?focusedCommentId=931837&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-931837)

```
use admin
db.system.users.remove({})    <== removing all users
db.system.version.remove({}) <== removing current version 
db.system.version.insert({ "_id" : "authSchema", "currentVersion" : 3 })
```

- you only need to downgrade the schema to create MONGODB-CR users.
  Once they are there the old drivers will work regardless of the value
  of authSchemaVersion. However if you run authSchemaUpgrade to change
  from "3" to "5" the users will obviously be upgraded.
- My comment regarding new users was that if you have existing SCRAM
  users and change the schema manually to "3" the user documents won't
  be consistent with the new schema. This is not enforced however but
  the SCRAM users will still work for any driver supporting SCRAM.

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade mongo-java-driver to 3.0.3 and use :-

MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential instead of MongoCredential.createMongoCRCredential

MongoCredential createMongoCRCredential = MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential(mongoConfiguration.getDatabaseUserName(), mongoConfiguration.getAuthenticationDatabase(),mongoConfiguration.getDatabasePassword().toCharArray());

http://docs.mongodb.org/master/release-notes/3.0-scram/

Comment: This was exactly the fix I was looking for to the issue I had. I had created the user initially using the cli mongo for version 3.2.4. It had created the user using the SHA1 process. My code was trying to connect using the previous CR process. Changing to the MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential() was by far the better fix rather than downgrading.

Answer (score 2):

For me I was using a mongo 2 client trying to connect to a mongo 3 server. Upgrading the client fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error as well.

Check your Spring Config file.. I had a constructor arg named "MONGODB-CR" which I swapped to "SCRAM-SHA-1" and it fixed my issue.

tailing the mongodb log file helped me diagnose this.

Answer (score 1):

- uninstall **mongodb-clients** packages provided by Ubuntu
- install **mongodb-org-shell** provided by official [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#packages)

This solved the problem, because The unofficial mongodb package provided by Ubuntu is not maintained by MongoDB. You should always use the official MongoDB mongodb-org packages, which are kept up-to-date with the most recent major and minor MongoDB releases.

Answer (score 0):

Probably old news, and problem solved, but adding my experience with the same error:

I had the exact same problem (using MongoDB 3.0), and a C# driver that was setup to use a pre 3.0 db.

In C# I used "MongoDB.Driver.CreateMongoCRCredentials()", which caused the error the OP was getting.

The fix (for me), was to switch the command above to "MongoDB.Driver.CreateCredential()".

I guess this could be caused by using "old" users (from pre 3.0) on an upgraded system.  Which either forces you to upgrade your users to the new authentication mechanism, or downgrade the authentication mechanism on your server.

Answer (score 0):

June 2018 I got this error after trying to connect to my Mongodb version 3.6 from an ancient client installed in /usr/bin. I installed the mongo DB in a separate folder outside of the OS standard directory, and so my installation was conflicting with the ancient version installed by the package manager.

Answer (score 0):

For those who is struggling to update auth schema (see the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31476552/2182901)) in MongoDB 3.6 due to the `not authorized on admin to execute command` and `removing FeatureCompatibilityVersion document is not allowed` errors, this is what's worked for me.

To resolve **the first error**:

```
> db.system.version.remove({})
WriteResult({
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 13,
                "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { update: \"system.version\", ordered: true, lsid: { id: UUID(\"58e86006-d889-440a-bd83-ad09fcd81747\") }, $db: \"admin\" }"
        }
})
```

I had to create a custom role that permits any action on any resource and a user with this role, then login to the admin database with that new user:

```
mongo admin

db.createUser({user: 'admin', pwd: 'mypwd', roles: ['root']})
exit

mongo admin -u admin -p

db.createRole({role: 'fullaccess', privileges: [{resource: {anyResource: true}, actions: ["anyAction"]}], roles: []})
db.createUser({user: 'superadmin', pwd: 'mypwd', roles: ['fullaccess']})
exit

mongo admin -u superadmin -p
```

*(Just using the `admin` user with `root` role or disabling `security.authorization` in config didn't work for me and still had the same error when trying to update the `system.version` table.)*

After that I had **another error**:

```
> db.system.version.remove({})
WriteResult({
        "nRemoved" : 0,
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 40670,
                "errmsg" : "removing FeatureCompatibilityVersion document is not allowed"
        }
})
```

To resolve it, we should only update the `authSchema` document instead of removing the whole collection.

*(Generally speaking, you shouldn't blindly remove everything from system tables in production and always check what would be the implications of updating them, so that's another reason to update the needed record only.)*

```
db.system.version.update({"_id": "authSchema"}, {currentVersion: 3})
```

Now you should be able to **create a user with the old authentication mechanism**. You also might need to switch to your database first, so that the user is created in that database rather than in `admin` one. Otherwise you'd have to use the `authSource=admin` parameter in your connection string.

*(I'm actually lying here - it still will be created in `admin` database, just with `mydb.myuser` id instead of `admin.myuser`. But I use the same way of describing these things that's being used in MongoDB documentation. I suppose this is how it actually used to work in previous versions and in general we shouldn't care about the internal implementation details.)*

```
use mydb
db.createUser({user: 'myuser', pwd: 'mypwd', roles: [{role: 'dbOwner', db: 'mydb'}]})
```

And don't forget to **cleanup**:

```
use admin
db.system.version.update({"_id": "authSchema"}, {currentVersion: 5})
exit

mongo admin -u admin -p

db.dropUser('superadmin')
db.dropRole('fullaccess')
```

You may want to keep the `admin` user - I was not able to create it again even with `security.authorization` setting disabled. It looks like if there are any records in `admin.system.users` table, the setting does not work anymore and mongo requires authentication to do something.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error with a Spring Boot app using a new MongoDB 3.2.8 database. By upgrading to the latest version of the Java Mongo driver (3.2.2) and then adding the authentication mechanism param to the URI in my application.properties, I was able to get it working:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://myusername:mypassword@localhost/?authSource=admin&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1
spring.data.mongodb.database=test
```