# MongoDB AuthenticationFailed with mechanism MONGODB-CR

Tags: mongodb

I've created these two users in my admin database:

```
db.auth('admin','password')
1
> db.getUsers()
[
    {
        "_id" : "admin.siteUserAdmin",
        "user" : "siteUserAdmin",
        "db" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
            {
                "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
                "db" : "admin"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : "admin.admin",
        "user" : "admin",
        "db" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
            {
                "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
                "db" : "admin"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I am uthenticated correctly from my localhost, but when I try to use an external client to get connected to my database I got this error:

```
Failed to authenticate admin@admin with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 8):

As stated [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authentication/): MongoDB 3  authentication mechanism has been changed from *MongoDB Challenge and Response* **(MONGODB-CR)** to *challenge and response mechanism* **(SCRAM-SHA-1)**.

You have to delete your created user then change *admin.system.version.authSchema* to **3** instead of **5**. Then recreating your user should solve the problem:

```
var schema = db.system.version.findOne({"_id" : "authSchema"})
schema.currentVersion = 3
db.system.version.save(schema)
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29006887/mongodb-cr-authentication-failed) link might be helpful too.

Answer (score 6):

My symptom is different from the above question but I am writing down here for reference.
I get an authentication error within local environment.
This happens for me when I use miss matching version between mongodb server and client.
For example:

- Server: the version of mongod is v3.4.2.
- Client: the version of mongo is 2.6.10.

When I access the server by mongo with valid user and password, it fails due to version miss-match.

Comment: Hey, it's a valid answer, indeed. Thanks! As a recommendation, I'd say that you should improve the text. Just a tip :)!