# MongoError: auth failed mongoose connection string

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, connection-string

I can connect to the DB through terminal, but getting this error using mongoose and gulp. 
mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:246
MongoError: auth failed

My connection string is:

```
mongodb://usr:psw@localhost:27017/dbname
```

Any idea what it can be?

Comment: For those who come looking for a solution, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49957410/13062813 is your answer

Answer (score 34):

I installed MEAN from [MEAN packaged by Bitnami](https://bitnami.com/stack/mean) for windows 7 using the following password: `123456`

Syntax for connection string to connect to `mongodb` with `mongoose` module

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://[usr]:[pwd]@localhost:[port]/[db]",{auth:{authdb:"admin"}});
```

If you don't have `{auth:{authdb:"admin"}}` in the connection string, you will get the following error: `MongoError: Authentication failed.`

**JS Example:** mongo-test/app.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://root:123456@localhost/test',{auth:{authdb:"admin"}});
mongoose.set('debug', true); // turn on debug
```

Comment: I added the `{auth:{authdb:"admin"}}` but still getting `"MongoError: auth failed"`

Answer (score 28):

just add `?authSource=yourDB&w=1` to end of db url

```
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:password@host/yourDB?authSource=yourDB&w=1')
```

this work for me . `&w=1` is important

Comment: yes, this worked for me. Quite strange that from pymongo, it doesn't need the authSource parameter.

Comment: mongoose.connect('mongodb://admin:password@localhost/some_db?authSource=admin&w=1',{})

Comment: what is the purpose of w=1?

Comment: @RyanGriggs The w option requests acknowledgment that the write operation has propagated to a specified number of mongod instances or to mongod instances with specified tags.

Answer (score 16):

There is many ways to make it work.  This is what worked for me [mongoose v5.9.15] :

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/', {
    auth: {
        user:'root',
        password:'example'
    },
    authSource:"admin",
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true
})
```

Comment: Had this issue when switching from the mongo node driver to mongoose. Used the same connection string, but I kept on getting the auth error. I added authSource='admin' and problem was solved.

Comment: In my case, ("mongoose": "^6.0.2")
"user" need to be changed as "username'

Answer (score 9):

You might want to do something like this...

```
var opt = {
    user: config.username,
    pass: config.password,
    auth: {
        authdb: 'admin'
    }
};
var connection = mongoose.createConnection(config.database.host, 'mydatabase', config.database.port, opt);
```

'authdb' option is the database you created the user under.

Comment: `Error [MongooseError]: Mongoose 5.x no longer supports ``mongoose.connect(host, dbname, port)`` or ``mongoose.createConnection(host, dbname, port)``. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html for supported connection syntax`
(yes I realize 5 years have passed... info for visitors)

Answer (score 8):

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://[host]/[db]", { auth:{

    authdb: "admin",
    user: [username],
    password: [pw]

}}).then(function(db){

    // do whatever you want

    mongoose.connection.close() // close db

})
```

Comment: This should be the default way in the documentation. All other ways lead to error and confusion. Congratulations!

Answer (score 5):

Do you have a user set up for dbname? By default, no user is required to connect to the database unless you explicitly set one. If you haven't, you should just try to connect to `mongodb://localhost:27017/dbname` and see if you still get an error.

Comment: I have a user and a password, otherwise the data will be available to everybody. I tried also with the root user, but the problem exist. I am using mongoose, just interested if anybody else issued similar problem...and solved)

Comment: same issue here. i noticed it only has problem when i make a second or higher number db link, not to the first one i made..

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution hier, looks like when you create an user from the mongo shell, it makes SCRAM-SHA-1 instead of MongoDB-CR. So the solution to create a new user with MongoDB-CR authentication.

[MongoDB-CR Authentication failed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31476552/3649420)

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. I will try it. But we have switched to sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

just make sure that your database is created.
and also if your user is not added in the admin database, then make sure to add it by putting 
db.createUser(
... {user:'admin',pwd:'admin',roles:['root']}
... )

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me for mongod --version = db version v3.6.13

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/expressapi', {
    auth: {
        authdb: "admin",
        user: "root",
        password: "root",

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mongo mongodb://usr:psw@localhost:27017/dbname
```

- Password should be alphanumeric only
- User should be also available in db 'dbname' (Note : Even if user is super admin)

With above changes it connected successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://[usr]:[pwd]@localhost:[port]/[db]",{ authSource: 'admin', useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
```

I was getting same error. Resolved by adding `authSource` option to connect function solved the issue. see above code.

Answer (score -1):

The connection string will be like

**mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/yourdbname?authSource=admin**