# Mongo connection failing from Mongoose but works from shell

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to connect to a Mongo app from my Node application using Mongoose. I have done this before on the same machine, but this time I am having a connection problem.

```
import { connect } from 'mongoose';

export class ConnectedModel {
   
  protected async connect(): Promise<void>() {
     const connectionString = 'mongodb://my-user-name:my-password@localhost/my-database';
     await connect(connectionString);
  }
}
```

This throws an error:

```
 /my-project/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:807
 const serverSelectionError = new ServerSelectionError();
                                ^ MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
     at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/my-project/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:807:32)
     // many lines of error stack
     at UserModel.connect (/my-project/bin/www/models/connected.model.js:6:38)
```

I thought the problem must be something to do with my credentials *but* if I use `mongo "mongodb://my-user-name:my-password@localhost/my-database"` from the command line it opens up the shell as the right user in the right database.

The user belongs to the database I am attempting to use, so I don't think this is an `authSource` problem and changing authSource has not had any effect so none of the solutions [on this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105823/mongoerror-auth-failed-mongoose-connection-string) are working for me.

Why does this connection string work from the command line but not through Mongoose? What do I need to change in order to be able to open the connection?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `ECONNREFUSED` error, which basically means the PORT you are trying to use in order to connect is being used.

> but if I use mongo "mongodb://my-user-name:my-password@localhost/my-database" from the command line it opens up the shell as the right user in the right database.

1. Did you close the connection?
2. You can try to change the default PORT number and try to reconnect.

Find the Info here - [Standard Connection String Format](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/#standard-connection-string-format)

TL;DR - Something like this `mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,...hostN[:portN]][/[defaultauthdb][?options]]`

3. Check CMD (in windows) if PORT is being used

Run CMD as admin then `netstat -an` and look for PORT 27017

Answer (score 0):

A bit weird but judging by [this Mongoose issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/11066) it looks as though there's a problem with it trying to resolve `localhost` using IPV6 while Mongo is not running in IPV6 mode. Changing the ConnectionString to `mongodb://my-user-name:my-password@127.0.0.1/my-database` has resolved the connection failure.

The issue suggests checking `/etc/hosts` to ensure that `127.0.0.1` is before `::1` but on my system that is already the case, so this might be something to do with the environment on the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're getting connect ECONNREFUSED error because you forgot to spin up MongoDB server.
After making sure you have MongoDB installed, open a new tab on your terminal and run the command:

```
mongod
```

Read: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-mongodb-a4ce205e7739/

Ref: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/program/mongod/#options