# MongoDB 3.0.2 issue login into collection

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

```
Failed to authenticate russell.harrower@admin with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document.
```

Now I have been using an older version of MongoDB and thought I would put the latest version on my new ubuntu home server. However I am now having an issue with using the admin user which I set up via.

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "siteUserAdmin",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

However it seems that when I use Robomongo it decides to say that I am unsuccessful, when I look at the logs I get the message above, could someone please let me know what I have to do to be able to login. Is this a RoboMongo issue or something else?

Comment: Which mongodb version did you use as previous one? Did you upgrade to `SCRAM-SHA-1` authentification?

Comment: You seem to have setup "siteUserAdmin" but are logging in using "russell.harrower@admin". Try logging in from the command line - if it works there, roboMongo will also work.

Comment: The issue is that Robomongo 0.8.x doesn't support the new default SCRAM-SHA-1 auth in MongoDB 3.0. See: https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/766.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB-CR Authentication failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29006887/mongodb-cr-authentication-failed)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `mongodump` to get backup from former version and `mongorestore` to restore new version it has to work. Actually it works for me. Good luck!

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-scram/#continue-to-use-mongodb-cr

Unfortunately there is no another way...