# Unable to connect to Mongo DB from R : Authentication Failed

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb

```
mongo -u User -p pass --port 2551 -authenticationDatabase=db
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.3
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:2551/test
>
```

Using the same username and password I get Authentication Issue in R.

```
> library(rmongodb)
> mongo <- mongo.create(host="<host>:2551", name="", username ="User", password = "pass", db="db")
Authentication failed.
>
```

Comment: Yes, correct and even below URL helped :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29006887/mongodb-cr-authentication-failed

Comment: Which is why you should be selecting the "Big Blue Button" that says "This solved my problem" or whatever it exactly says rather than continuing to edit your question and comment. The idea is that you confirm the duplicate yourself, rather than many of us needing to close it for you. Which we will anyway