# How to assign authentication mechanism to user in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I created a user in MongoDB using

```
db.createUser({user:"admin", pwd:"admin", role : [{role:"readWrite", db:"someDB"}]});
```

But I assume this user has been created with the default authentication mechanism. So if I want to authenticate only using, lets say SRAM-SHA-256, I tried doing

```
db.createUser({user: "test", pwd:"test", role:[{role:"readWrite", db}], mechanisms: [ "SCRAM-SHA-256" ]})
```

But this doesn't seem to work. It is throwing an error

```
Error: couldn't add user: "mechanisms" is not a valid argument to createUser
```

How to do this ? I am using MongoDB version 3.6.18

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/parameters/#param.authenticationMechanisms

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because **MongoDB version 3.6 doesn't support the mechanisms argument for db.createUser() function**, you can check that in [MongoDB 3.6 Doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/method/db.createUser/#db.createUser)

And also the mechanism **SCRAM-SHA-256** you are trying to implement doesn't work in MongoDB 3.6, it was introduced in MongoDB 4.0, you can check that on [SCRAM-SHA-1 and SCRAM-SHA-256 DOC](https://docs.cloudmanager.mongodb.com/tutorial/edit-host-authentication-credentials/#scram-sha-1-and-scram-sha-256)

And as written in the latest [MongoDB Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/), by default in 3.6 it's SCRAM-SHA-1 and you can't change it.

> mechanisms -  The default for featureCompatibilityVersion is 3.6 is SCRAM-SHA-1

Comment: Oh so do you mean we can only have SCRAM-SHA-1 in 3.6 and not any other mechanisms?

Comment: Yes, because they added mechanisms in 4.0, and before that by default its was  SCRAM-SHA-1

Comment: You can bypass this, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64931171/2182901